# AngularJS "ng-repeat | filter:..." not working as I would expect (shows no data)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn some AngularJS. I have a small page hosted locally which looks up information in MySQL. The fields are [user_ID, comment, user_Name].

Here is the webpage's code:
    
  
    AngularJS Test

```
<div id="container" ng-app='two_way' ng-controller='two_way_control'>
    <input ng-model="name_filter" placeholder="filter names">
    <p>{{name_filter}}</p>
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="data in profile_pictures | filter:{data.user_Name:name_filter}">
    <div class=".col-sm-6 .col-md-5 .col-lg-6" style="background-color:#eee;height:125px;width:500px;margin-left:240px;margin-top:20px;">
      <h4 style="padding:10px;">{{data.user_Name}} says:</h4><hr>
      <p style="padding:10px;">
        {{data.comment}}
      </p>
      <img src="{{data.profile_picture}}" class="img-circle" style="width:100px;height:100px;margin-left:-140px;margin-top:-130px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem I am having is regarding the filter for "data in profile_pictures"

I'm trying to filter just by the user_Name field. When I type anything into the input box on the site, no data is displayed (everything disappears). I have tried hardcoding the filter to be a name I know is in the data, but that just shows no data when I load the page.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid syntax in your filter. You need to provide the key name of the object as the filter object, do not use dot notation for the object key @`filter:{data.user_Name:name_filter}"`

i.e try

```
ng-repeat="data in profile_pictures | filter:{user_Name:name_filter}"
```

Comment: Yes that was the solution! I am used to using VBA and SQL Server so I missed the dot notation problem. Thanks for the help